# How to stop tkinter OptionMenu that contains checkbutton from closing when an item is checked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu, tkinter.checkbutton

I have an OptionMenu widget what I added some checkbuttons. It keeps closing when an item is check and I want it to stop doing this here's the code

```
drop1=OptionMenu(frame2, variable=clicked1,value="Options :")
other_variables={}
for o in other:
drop1['menu'].addcheckbutton(label=o,onvalue=1,offvalue=2,variable=var4, command=checkedOther)
```

> Other is a list containing the items that need to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop the menu from closing, but you can show it back inside `checkedOther()` function:

```
def checkedOther(*args):
    # show the popup menu
    x, y, h = drop1.winfo_rootx(), drop1.winfo_rooty(), drop1.winfo_height()
    drop1['menu'].post(x, y+h)
```

Comment: the x,y,h variables mean what

Comment: `(x, y)` is the coordinates of the top-left corner of `drop1` in the root window and `h` is the height of `drop1`.  So `(x, y+h)` is the coordinates of the bottom-left corner of `drop1`.

Comment: the checkedOther function in my program is used to store the selected options should I still put the program in it or create a new function to store it in

Comment: You can still do whatever you do after showing the menu inside the function.